# jQuery onChange() get another field focused

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please visit this fiddle first: http://jsfiddle.net/7Prys/

What I want to get when user inputs the first fields (user can input only one string per field) the second one get focused in automatically, and this continues until the fourth input field. Is there a quick jQuery for it? And also when I delete the code the previous one will be focused one by one on pressing the backspace key.

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="small" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="small" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="small" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="small" />
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".small").onchange(function () {
    $(this).next().find(".small").focusIn();
});
```

Comment: Please avoid edits which invalidate existing answers or render them incomplete. If you need additional detail, consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(".small").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8){ /* backspace */
        $(this).prev('.small').focus();
    }else{
        $(this).next('.small').focus();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Prys/10/
This will go to the next input when any key other than backspace is pressed, and go to the previous input when backspace is pressed. Note that you can add `|| e.keyCode == 46` the the if statement if you want to recognize the Delete key.

---

There is no such thing as `.onChange` or `.focusIn`. `.on` can be used for the `keyup` event as in my example. Also, `.find().next('.small')` should just be `.next('.small')`.

Comment: For what it's worth, `.on` is generally better practice because it is consistent with other events such as `click`, `mouseover`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
$(".small").keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8){
        $(this).prev('.small').focus();
    }
    else {
      $(this).next('.small').focus();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sv2f/

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(".small").keyup(function () {
    $(this).next().focus();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7Prys/4/)**

A few notes. In jQuery you use `.change()`, not `.onchange()`. Second, `.find()` searches through descendant elements, so it your example it would never find the right element since they're siblings.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of issues here.

`onchange` should be `change`, but that will only be triggered when the input loses focus, which doesn't work so well.  I suggest using `.keyup`.

`$(this).next()` is the input element, so `$(this).next().find(".small")` won't find anything.  You could use `$(this).next(".small")`, but `$(this).next()` is sufficient.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/7Prys/6/

EDIT: you can check `e.which == 8` to determine if the backspace was pressed and then use `.prev` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/7Prys/11/

Answer (score 2):

There is **no such thing** as the on change event.

There **is** a `change` event you can use.

Comment: @aks007 there is no such thing as `focusIn`

Answer (score 0):

it's .change() not .onChange()

http://api.jquery.com/change/